# How to update a value based on the value of another column which has occurred at least once

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have the following table:

| Location | DBFire | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NewYork | 1 | Completed |
| NewYork | NULL | In Progress |
| London | 1 | Completed |
| London | NULL | In Progress |
| Cairo | 1 | Completed |
| Cairo | NULL | In Progress |
| Cairo | NULL | In Progress |

I want to convert this into :

| Location | DBFire | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| NewYork | 1 | Completed |
| NewYork | NULL | Completed |
| London | 1 | Completed |
| London | NULL | Completed |
| Cairo | 1 | Completed |
| Cairo | NULL | Completed |
| Cairo | NULL | Completed |

The idea is to update the table in such a way so that, for the same location if the DBFire value is "1" at least once, then the *Status* column must show **Completed**

Please suggest a simple SQL statement , preferrably **UPDATE**

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: Your sample data seems like all belong to same scenario. Please include samples for other scenario also

Comment: this is the only scenario